# Calendar control in boostrap + asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, calendar

Good night everyone!

I'm stuck with a calendar control developed in bootstrap.

All my .js and scripts are on a master page.

The issue is:

When i have to use this control with a  works well:

```
<input class="form-control" id="date" name="date" placeholder="Click aquí" type="text" />
```

[Working well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yHqw.png)

When i use an asp textbox this don't work

```
<asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" id="date" name="date" placeholder="Click aquí" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

[Not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aywYO.png)

I think the problem comes from use a server control or some like this.

This is the script code (in master page):

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var date_input = $('input[name="date"]'); //our date input has the name "date"
        var container = $('.bootstrap-iso form').length > 0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
        var options = {
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            container: container,
            todayHighlight: true,
            autoclose: true,
        };
        date_input.datepicker(options);
        return false;
    })        
</script>
```

¿How i can solve this? ¿Or i can handle the input type in html from c# code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ASP.NET Web Form, server-side id and name won't be necessarily same as client-side rendered code. You can look at them in chrome developer tool.

[image]

The easiest way to fix is to add `datepicker` class to `TextBox`, and target as `input.datepicker`.

```
<asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control datepicker" id="date" 
   name="date" placeholder="Click aquí" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var date_input = $('input.datepicker');
        ...
    })        
</script>
```

By doing so, you can just add `datepicker` to any textbox whenever you want a calendar control.

Comment: Ohh man works like a charm! Now i have a nice tip to work with this! Lot of thanks for you brother!